# jQuery.support that will pass IE10+ but not IE9-?

Tags: jquery, browser-detection, jquery-1.10

Are there any `jQuery.support` options that will return true on IE10 as well as Firefox and Webkit browsers, but return false on IE9 and lower?

The jquery page for this option seems woefully out of date.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

If someone has another suggestions I'd be open to it. (Using jQuery 1.10)

Comment: oops nothing find in terms of question. What is the question?

Comment: @Jai The first sentence is the question. That is why it has a question mark at the end of it.

Comment: @Jai, I will edit for clarity by adding a link to explain jQuery.support

Comment: Have you tried some of them which are not at all supported in IE. May be they are supported in IE 10, and the jquery documentation has not been updated yet

Answer (score 1):

If you just want browser version detection:

```
$.browser.msie
$.browser.version
```

Note that in general this is a bad idea, and you should be coding to features that are available in whatever browser you're using.  But if you have some specific reason, use these.

Comment: can't use this because it is no longer in jquery 1.9

Comment: @kylex - Oh, you're right... It's in jquery migrate now: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.min.js